# gcc segmentation fault on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, compiling, gcc, segmentation-fault

I am trying to compile a C program on Ubuntu precise 12.04.
Here's the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  printf("Hello World!");
  return 0;
}
```

My gcc version is 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5).
Initially it did not find cc1 so I added a soft link.
Now I get this message when I try to compile:

```
gcc: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault (program cc1)
```

Compiling the same program with g++ works fine.

I tried reinstalling build-essential, but to no avail.
What am I missing?

EDIT: I tried reinstalling according to @gertyvdijk's suggestion. As it did not help, here is
the output of `apt-cache policy gcc-4.6`:

```
  gcc-4.6:  Installed: 4.6.3-1ubuntu5
  Candidate: 4.6.3-1ubuntu5
  Version table:
 *** 4.6.3-1ubuntu5 0
        500 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

and the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/gcc`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Mar 13  2012 /usr/bin/gcc -> gcc-4.6
```

EDIT #2: here's a verbose compiler output:

```
    gcc -v aaa.c 
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.6 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/cc1 -quiet -v -imultilib . -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu aaa.c -quiet -dumpbase aaa.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase aaa -version -fstack-protector -o /tmp/ccHfcXMs.s
gcc: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault (program cc1)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs> for instructions.
```

Comment: Try `cc <filename.c>`.

Comment: "I tried reinstalling build-essential" - That's just a metapackage. You'll have to reinstall the plain GCC packages to properly reinstall all `gcc` binaries. Try `apt-get reinstall gcc gcc-4.6 gcc-4.6-base libgcc1`. If that does not work, please also provide the output of `apt-cache policy gcc-4.6` and `ls -l /usr/bin/gcc` in your question.

Comment: Did not work. Please see the updated question.

Comment: GCC package installation looks all good. I am unable to reproduce this using the exact same gcc version and the source you provided - binary returns "Hello World!" as expected. It could be that a Bash alias in your user profile is the culprit. Could you try to invoke gcc using this more explicit command?`/usr/bin/gcc sourcefile.c -o helloworld`. Oh and I meant `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gcc gcc-4.6 gcc-4.6-base libgcc1` in my previous comment. (there's no such action as `apt-get reinstall`.)

Comment: Thanks Gert, but the full path gives the same result. I have added a verbose compiler output - maybe you will be able to see something off there.

Comment: Re-reading "Initially it did not find cc1 so I added a soft link." <-- What **exactly** did you do and **why**? I now think you mean `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/cc1` from the `cpp-4.6` package - was it absent? It should just be there - it's a hard dependency of gcc. Try reverting the symbolic link you created and reinstall that package.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks. Please build an answer from your comments, so I can upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This segmentation fault really should not happen. I suspect something is wrong with the binaries installed on your system - possibly because of the symbolic link you created.

Try reinstalling GCC and all affecting libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gcc gcc-4.6 gcc-4.6-base libgcc1 cpp-4.6
```

Specifically the [cpp-4.6 [image: Install cpp-4.6]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/cpp-4.6) package appears to be broken in your setup as `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/cc1` belongs to that package and the error output you've provided indicates the cause of the issue is in there somewhere.

Comment: The version need to be the same as the installed cc1. In my case was 4.8 "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/cc1". So the command `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gcc gcc-4.8 gcc-4.8-base libgcc1 cpp-4.8` did the trick

Comment: Still getting the 'segmentation fault'

Comment: Thanks, the following worked for me: 
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall gcc gcc-4.9 gcc-4.9-base libgcc1 cpp-4.9`
 Note: this is actually on Raspian Jessy.